# Spring Data JPA: How do I ensure that nested OneToMany objects are cascaded when the main object is saved?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Problem with cascading saving of nested objects in Spring Data JPA

I have encountered a problem when using Spring Data JPA related to cascading saving of nested objects in OneToMany communication. When I try to save the main entity (e.g. Product), the related entities (e.g. ProductVariant ) are not automatically saved.

Here are my entities:

**Product:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "handle", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String handle;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ProductVariant> variants;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_images",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id"))
    private List<Image> images;
}
```

**ProductVariant:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_variant")
@Data
public class ProductVariant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "sku")
    private String sku;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Product product;
}
```

If the service is described in detail and relations are added manually, it works correctly:

```
    public Product createProduct(Product productRequest) {
        Product product = new Product();

        product.setTitle(productRequest.getTitle());
        product.setHandle(productRequest.getHandle());

        List<ProductVariant> variants = new ArrayList<>();
        if (productRequest.getVariants() != null) {
            for (ProductVariant variantRequest : productRequest.getVariants()) {
                ProductVariant variant = new ProductVariant();
                variant.setName(variantRequest.getName());
                variant.setSku(variantRequest.getSku());
                variant.setProduct(product);
                variants.add(variant);
            }
        }

        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
        if (productRequest.getImages() != null) {
            for (Image imageRequest : productRequest.getImages()) {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.setName(imageRequest.getName());
                image.setAlt(imageRequest.getAlt());
                image.setUrl(imageRequest.getUrl());
                images.add(image);
            }
        }

        product.setVariants(variants);
        product.setImages(images);

        return productRepository.save(product);
    }
```

But in a good way it should work this way automatically as well, or am I misunderstanding something?

```
    public Product createProduct(Product productRequest) {
        return productRepository.save(productRequest);
    }
```

I would like to point out that in both cases, when I send a request through Postman, I get a response containing variants, but if I have the service on the second example, looking in the database the product_id of the variant is not specified

Comment: I didn't attach the Image class to the question because it is saved correctly as expected because of @JoinTable, but with Variants it's a problem

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem, maybe someone else will:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<ProductVariant> variants;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Product product;
```

We needed to add two annotations @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference and it works